# C - scanf behaving strangely

Tags: c, scanf

I am working on a simple c program that takes a command and runs a simple C function, so you wouldn't have to compile a whole program to see it work. It was working fine until `scanf`, when I tried to take input. I wanted to be efficient and first split the input by space, which I made a function for up above. Then have if statements compare the first item, which would be the command name. But whenever I run it, it behaves strangely when it starts making multiple new lines and printing out the inputted text. I would like it to store the first item of the split text in a variable and print the first item but instead it prints out each item sequentially. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void displayHeader(){
    printf("SuperCMD version 1.3. \nType \"help\" for a list of commands.\n");
}
char * strspltf(char * str, char * delim, int index){
    char * pch = strtok(str, delim);
    int i = 0;
    while(pch != NULL){
        if(i == index){
            return pch;
        }
        pch = strtok(NULL, delim);
        i++;
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(){
    displayHeader();
    char command[] = "";
    char dir[] = "C:\\";
    while(strcmp(command, "exit") != 0){
        printf("%s > ", dir);
        scanf("%s", command);
        char * res = strspltf(command, " ", 0);
        printf("%s\n", strspltf(command, " ", 0));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The function on top returns the specific index of a string split by another string. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it? Also when I type "exit" it crashes. Why's that?

Comment: this line: `char command[] = "";` produces an array that is only 1 char long and contains a NUL byte.   TO work correctly, that line should be similar to: `char command[ 100 ] = {'\0'};`  which would create an array of 100 characters and initialize it to all NUL bytes

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the `%s` input format conversion specifier, always include a MAX CHARACTERS modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer, so the input buffer can not be overrun. Overrunning the input buffer results in undefined behavior and can lead to a seg fault event

Comment: Note: the call to `scanf()` with the `%s` format specifier will stop at the first 'white space' encountered (and a space is 'white space') so no space will ever be read.  Probably not what you want.  Suggest using `[^\n]` or better `fgets()` to input the characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
char command[] = "";
```

is wrong.  You have not allocated and space for the array other than one empty string.  You then call  `scanf("%s", command);`  since no memory has been allocated to hold the result of the scanf, you are overwriting the stack with garbage.  Change declaration to something like:

```
#define MAX_COMMAND 50   // or whatever size you need.
char command[MAX_COMMAND];
```

...

Comment: it's also safer to use told `scanf` not to get more than `MAX_COMMAND - 1` characters, otherwise it'll invoke undefined behavior

Comment: I used `char command[50];` now, but it's still behaving weird.

Comment: @Garhoogin,  that is not really a fix unless you changed the length of the array `command[]` to also be 256

Comment: I did that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Your local variable `command` is a single element array. It is not big enough to hold the input command entered by the user as `scanf` input.

Redefine `command` as an array of say 100 elements.

`char command[100];`